# Spring Boot not working?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have generate a standard spring boot sample using command

```
spring init
```

The outcome is a plain Java project with a pom like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>demo.DemoApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I hit

```
spring run src/main/java/demo/DemoApplication.java
```

It kicks me out with an error message such as

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertySourceBootstrapConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.List org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.propertySourceLocators; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configServicePropertySource' defined in class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration$PropertySourceLocatorConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator]: Factory method 'configServicePropertySource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/client/HttpServerErrorException
```

That I cannot explain.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please include DemoApplication.java and the full log from spring run command?

Comment: here you are
Full Log: http://pastebin.com/aQzPLvNx

DemoApplication.java: http://pastebin.com/Gwt3GfTA

Here is the full project, with changes suggested by @lkrnac
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5674395/spring-boot-demo.zip

Comment: That's very strange. I can run this application without any problem. What OS are you using? Can you include --debug option when running the app and include the full log from beginning to end?

Comment: spring run src/main/java/demo/DemoApplication.java --debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of tags on this question is spring-mvc, so I assume your want to use Web Spring features. 
To enable Spring web features you need to add this Spring Boot this dependency into POM:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I haven't use Spring CLI before, therefore I am not familiar why it didn't generate project with Web dependencies. But I would bet you need to explicitly specify somehow that to want to generate web project.

So you probably generated plain Spring Boot project without web dependencies and added some web related configuration into application.properties. Therefore Spring Boot auto configurer is trying to find web dependencies on your classpath.

Comment: Unfortunately I've added the dependency, but it did not work. the error is still the same: http://pastebin.com/aQzPLvNx

Comment: Here the full project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5674395/spring-boot-demo.zip

Comment: Test and application itself works fine. I believe the problem will be in the way you are running it. By default this is fat JAR application with embedded container and you need to run it via  DemoApplication.main method.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this already have an answer, this same issue can come up with corrupted maven dependencies. So anyone who could not solve the same issue try deleting the artifacts (or the full local repo) from

`c:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository` by hand or try running `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`

and reload the projects in the IDE.